# FB Messenger PSID: Do I need to complete account link to receive a PSID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

Do I need account link to receive a PSID? Or is the senderID I receive in the post body whenever an user messages already the PSID?

Comment: What can possibly be unclear about https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/conversation#receive_messages ?

Comment: Account link = account linking ? If you mean it. Its False :)
You are getting PSID when you write to the page.